# Disable "Autocompletion"/"Abbreviation" in Verilog-Mode

Tags: spacemacs, abbrev, verilog

When I use the Verilog Mode in *spacemacs* with evil keybindings, every time I type e.g. `wire` and press `ESC`, an automatic dialouge pops up and asks me `msb:`, `lsb:`  and `name (RET to end)`.
This is super annoying, since pressing `ESC` in the prompt often leads to three blank lines and an open bracket.

Apparently this is defined in the *verilog-define-abbrev-table* in the [verilog-mode.el](https://www.veripool.org/ftp/verilog-mode.el), but I don't speak lisp, nor do I have deeper knowledge of emacs packages.

Changing the verilog-mode.el file is not possible, since I'm working on a multi user Server without sudo rights.

How can I disable the whole abbreviation-autocompletion stuff in the verilog mode?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that abbrev minor mode is disabled

Comment: Ok, editing the abbrev file with `edit-abbrevs` helps, but this buffer gets reset after a restart. How to disable the abbrevs or clean the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Solution: the verilog-mode does fill the "abbrev-table" every time it gets initialized.

I added a hook to my spacemacs-dotfile which clears the table after the mode is initialized:

```
(defun my-verilog-setup ()
    (clear-abbrev-table verilog-mode-abbrev-table))
(add-hook 'verilog-mode-hook #'my-verilog-setup)
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your answer after the grace period.

Comment: This is super useful... nicely done.

Comment: This was driving me insane, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found an [alternative solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/evil-mode-unwanted-abbrev-expand-setq-evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit-ni), which is to set `evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit` to non-nil. This way, you can still keep the abbrev, either by enabling the mode or [via](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html#Expanding-Abbrevs) <kbd>C-x a e</kbd> or `expand-abbrev`.

I just customized the variable via <kbd>SPC h d v</kbd> (there are other ways of course). In the help of that variable, it says "This variable is read only on load.", which meant a refresh of `.spacemacs` via <kbd>SPC f e R</kbd> didn't set this to the new value. Without knowing another way, a restart of spacemacs did the job.