# evil-mode unwanted abbrev expand (setq evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit nil)

Tags: evil, abbrev

Upon escaping evil-insert-state, if the cursor is next to a letter/phrase in my abbrev list, it expands despite having

```
(setq evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit nil)
```

called before evil-mode. This happens even if abbrev-mode is disabled.

How do I prevent abbrev expansion when exiting evil-insert-state?

Thanks.

Comment: Chances are you're doing it incorrectly, like by enabling another Evil-related package before that setting. Figuring out what exactly is going wrong is hard for us, as we don't have access to your specific Emacs environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, @wasamasa. Seeing your reply, I moved

```
(setq evil-want-abbrev-expand-on-insert-exit nil)
```

to the line before

```
(use-package evil
        :ensure t).
```

(Previously, it was before (evil-mode 1) but *after* the use-package command.)

The abbrev expansions now work as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You should read the `use-package` documentation because it most certainly covers how to do configuration *before* loading a package.